# Animate Dead: Any other undead minions?

Tags: dnd-5e, necromancy

I know Animate Dead can give you skeletons or zombies (your choice), and Create Undead can give you Ghouls, Ghasts, Wights, or Mummies.

Is there any other WotC material expanding upon the types of undead you can have? either through spells or magic items or "other"?

Answer (score 2):

You've got most of the options right there. There are a few others, although none are nearly as convenient:

- A Necromancy Wizard can have 1 of any type of undead using their Command Undead feature.
- Similarly, the *Dominate Monster* spell can potentially let you have any type of undead.
- The *Shapechange* spell lets you turn into any type of undead - it also lets you turn into a shadow dragon, to create shadows under your control with Shadow Breath, or a Wraith, to create specters under your control with Create Specter.
- A Moonblade, with the right properties, will let you have a shadow for a minion.